Spring Boot Repository layer Query created at runtime with params
Can I write below code in some way either native or jpql? Due to some constraints I want to have things added at runtime for repository layer java file.
jpqL:
 @Query("SELECT * FROM Schema.Road WHERE status IN (" + MyClass.getRightStatusList() + ")")
List<Rescue> findByStatusIn(); 

native:
List<Rescue> findByStatusIn("SELECT * FROM Schema.Road WHERE status IN (" + String.join(",", MyClass.getRightStatusList()) + "))", nativeQuery = true); 

Both the above way are not allowed
